# Dropwizard Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build() returns html

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

In case of a genuine missing resource, my API returns the following

```
{
    "code": 404,
    "message": "HTTP 404 Not Found"
}
```

When I return a 404 through my resource using the code `Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build()` I get the following HTML as response

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>URI:</th>
            <td>/v1/2/1/100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>STATUS:</th>
            <td>404</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>MESSAGE:</th>
            <td>Not Found</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SERVLET:</th>
            <td>io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer-21c99abf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can block this unintended HTML and respond with no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Jersey property [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR) to `true`.

```
environment.jersey()
        .property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
```

---

> ```
> public static final String RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR
> ```
>
> Whenever response status is 4xx or 5xx it is possible to choose between `sendError` or `setStatus` on container specific `Response` implementation. E.g. on servlet container Jersey can call `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(...)` or `HttpServletResponse.sendError(...)`.
>
> Calling `sendError(...)` method usually resets entity, response headers and provide error page for specified status code (e.g. servlet `error-page` configuration). However if you want to post-process response (e.g. by servlet filter) the only way to do it is calling `setStatus(...)` on container Response object.
>
> If property value is `true` the method `Response.setStatus(...)` is used over default `Response.sendError(...)`.
>
> Type of the property value is `boolean`. The default value is `false`.
>
> The name of the configuration property is `"jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError"`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Worked like a charm. No hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and solved it by setting the `.entity(...)` to an empty String:

```
Response.status(NOT_FOUND).entity("").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build()
```

Since that's kind of a hack, I am also eager to learn about cleaner solution(s) ... ;)

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63415332/2587435)