# Avoid returning HTML when throwing an exception in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs, cxf

I have an application based on Jax-RS using CXF and Tomcat.

When my application throw a Exception, an ExceptionMapper is call :

```java
@Component
public class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException exception) {
        return Response
                .status(500)
                .entity(new ExceptionBodyResponse(exception))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Then I except a response with a custom XML message. But what I get is the Tomcat HTML error page (containing the wanted message inside).

I try to figure out how to receive the response without the Tomcat error page, only the XML.
I found another thread about this problematic, but for Jersey, nothing for CXF : [Dropwizard Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build() returns html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056592/dropwizard-response-statusresponse-status-not-found-build-returns-html/63415332#63415332)

Comment: If the same thing doesn't happen with success response, it might be deserialization problem? If you just use a String inside response entity does it still happen?

Comment: (in regards to your link) I wonder if you can do this in a servlet filter. I've never tried it.